# 2008 R2 RDS Client Printers Disappearing?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, citrix, printer, rds, provisioning

So my issue is something I can find nothing on and is very hard to track down.  I am working with Microsoft and Citrix support but am getting nowhere and my client is becoming frustrated on the lack of movement, which is why I'm posting here!

The situation:
I have a provisioned set of 9 2008 R2 Datacenter servers all running off of a single image provisioned by PVS , they usually use Citrix XenDesktop 7.5 to deliver themselves to this client's users, but this issue persists when using Citrix, RDP, and the Vsphere Console.

Now for the issue:
If a user logs into one of the RDS servers, lets say server 9, they get their local printers mapped into RDS normally.  Most users are remote so we want the servers to pull in their local printers.  Now, lets say an admin decides to log onto the RDS server and logs into server 9 just like the user.  When the admin is presented with a desktop the users locally mapped printers disappear.  It does not matter what form of connection we use to get onto the RDS server, for the user we can use Citrix (ICA) or direct RDP and their printers will map through, but when the admin logs in via Vsphere Console, Citrix, or RDP the printers disappear from all users logged onto that server, in this case server 9.

Our testing steps so far include disabling ALL gpo inheritance for a test OU and moving a test user, a test admin, and a test RDS server running on the same production image into said OU.  I have verified that nothing but the Local policy is applying for both user and computer but still printers disappear.  Microsoft attempted to recreate the RDP Listener but that did not work either.
If you have any questions about what has been done or about the environment let me know!

I have looked all over the internet and possibly thousands of posts and found nothing similar to this, you guys are my last option! Please if you know of anything related to this or can think of possible solutions let me know!

Comment: Do each of your VM's have a unique windows machine security ID?